# Custom style for input with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a design for input like this:

[image: Design]

But with my style, I can't do that.

My CSS:

```
input.custom[type=text]{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00CCCB;
}

.custom::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #727272;
}

.custom:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #727272;  
}

.custom::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #727272;  
}

.custom:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #727272;  
}
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="custom" placeholder="Text goes here"/>
```

Results:

[image: Result]

How can I style an input with bottom border **and tiny left, right borders**, like in my design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap the `input` in a `span` and style the `:before` and `:after` on that accordingly. You will need to use a `span` as `input`s are replaced elements, without psuedo elements you can style.

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00CCCB;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:before,
span:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #00CCCB;
  position: absolute;
}
span:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span><input /></span>
```

Comment: You beat me to it, imo the only solution (and a nice one! +1)

Comment: The -3px on the bottom of the pseudo elements is causing an issue for me in Chrome. -1px keeps them in line. Not downvoting, it will just need a tweak for cross browsers that's all - still a good solution :)

Comment: @SW4, sorry but i think  bottom: -3px; should be -1px so the look will be more good..

Comment: @Leothelion - actually, -3px is not incorrect in certain browsers, the value should *actually* be zero, with the correct BFC set on both the pseudos and span- see updated

Comment: @SW4, i did no say that -3px is incorrect but i just found border beyond the bottom border(tested in chrome and ff) then i thought to tell you..just wanted to share..nothing else..

Comment: @Leothelion of course :) All good- just thought it best to explain the reasoning, cause and demonstrate the fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated Link

http://jsfiddle.net/4dvkbtpg/10/

css code:

```
input {
  border: none;
  border-radius:2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00CCCB;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
span:before,
span:after {
  content: '';
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #00CCCB;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without adding new markup you can play with both `border-bottom` and `linear-gradients`, e.g.

```css
input {

   font           : 50px Arial;
   padding        : 5px 10px;
   border         : 8px transparent solid;
   border-bottom  : 8px #bada5a solid;
   background     : 

      /* 2) this partially overlaps the previous gradient by
       * applying a white background in the middle of the element
       * and leaving at both of the sides the background 1)
       * for the defined tickness 
       */
      linear-gradient(to right, transparent 8px, #fff 8px, 
             #fff calc(100% - 8px), transparent calc(100% - 7px)), 

      /* 1) this defines the offset from top for both the 
       * left and right border 
       */
      linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 60%, #bada5a 60%);

   background-origin: border-box;
}
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpbjQL?editors=1100) (tested on Firefox and Chrome)

---

This goes beyond your question but in that snippet I created — for the sake of code reusability — a SASS mixin that accepts as arguments the border-color, the tickness (in `px`) and the offset (in `%`) from top for the left and right border.

If you don't use a CSS preprocessor, just set your arguments in the codepen example and then switch to the compiled view, so you can grab the CSS code

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Now you can try to this**

```css
.inputsec{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #00CCCB;
}
.inputsec:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-left: solid 2px #00CCCB;
}
.inputsec:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-right: solid 2px #00CCCB;
}


.inputsec > input {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px 8px 4px 8px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputsec">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your text" />
</div>
```