# Partial vertical borders on form input

Tags: css, sass

**GOAL:**

I am trying to create partial vertical borders on a form input. The desired effect is the following:

[image]

**PROBLEM:**

Pseudo before and after elements are not permitted for inputs so this is not an option. Alternatively, using height to limit the size of the input with border left and right cuts off the text.

**LIMITS:**

No extra HTML elements or images can be used, this has to work using just CSS.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:**

I tried to create a gradient border with limited steps but was unable to configure it for individual border sides.

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
    input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], textarea {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 0 $size-xs;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: $size-m;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $clr-darker;
        display: block;
     }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31071140/1098851

Comment: Thanks, I did search for this on SO, perhaps I didn't use the correct phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with gradient for each side like this:

```css
input {
 border:none;
 padding:10px;
 background:
   /* Bottom side*/
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom      /100% 2px ,
   /* Left side */
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom left /2px 10px,
   /* Right side */
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom right/2px 15px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text">
```

Comment: Almost but the left border is much shorter than the right border.

Comment: @Alex i know :) i did it to show that you can control them separately ;)

Comment: @Alex you may notice the 25px and 10px :)

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realise, this works then will mark as correct shortly.